# Bulgaria visa type c number entries 2

Tags: visas, romania, bulgaria, jordanian-citizens

Im jordanian and have bulgaria visa type c number entries 2  i want book flight from amman to bucharest
Then back to amman with out enter bulgaria
Can i do that